# Java Swing Как определить по какой JLabel произошел клик?

Tags: java

На JPane есть несколько JLabel по которым слушается событие клика. В зависимости от того, по какой метке был клик - меняется логика. Мне необходимо по клику передать некий параметр, по которому я точно определю "источник" клика. 
У JLabel есть метод .getText(), который позволяет получить в обработчике текст метки, собственно есть вариант в текст писать что-то типа "Название метки id=1" и потом парсить эту строку. Но решение представляется мне не эстетичным, так как данная информация не нужна пользователю. Попробовал использовать <html><input type = "hidden" value = "1"></html>, строка перестает отображаться, но и getText() ее уже не видит. 
Подскажите, 1. Поможет ли парсинг html. 2. Как лучше передать параметр клика.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) ты можешь вызвать метод e.getSource() который вернет Object, у данного обьекта еще заранее необходимо будет установить имя label.setName("sname_label"), будешь обращатся к Object, предварительно кастанув его в JLabel, а дальше сможешь забрать имя метки getName();